# Suggestion of best practices for implementing a Web Chat

Tags: php, html, actionscript, chat

I want to develop a good chat in my page, I know how to program in php, actionscript 2 and 3, and how to manage MySQL databases.

So, given that I know to program, what do you suggest? Any good tutorials for making one? good open source projects? Implication of using this technologies in chats?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a web live chat? PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684288/how-to-make-a-web-live-chat-php)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302271

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use IRC - this way you don't have to worry about the server aspect.

Also, you should take a look at this Ajax-based IRC PHP Client:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/mibbit-ajax-based-irc-client

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://rad-dev.org/lithium_anologue/source) for how other people have implemented something similar. Perhaps consider an IRC backend to avoid creating your own system.